# Jquery select li outside ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code (markup was changed! TNX):

```
<div class="categories">
  <div class="category">
    <a>category 1</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="subcategories">
    <li class="subcategory">
      <a>subcategory 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="subcategory">
      <a>subcategory 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="category">
    <a>category 2</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="subcategories">
    <li class="subcategory">
      <a>subcategory 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="subcategory">
      <a>subcategory 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="subcategory">
      <a>subcategory 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to get the text of the category when user click on the subcategory.
for example: click on "subcategory 2" give me the text "category 1"

Comment: not a valid markup

Comment: Please show what you have tried. SO isn't the place to get people to do the work for you

Comment: There should not be *any* `<li>` elements outside of a `<ul>` or `<ol>`; that is, as pointed out, entirely invalid HTML.

Comment: This is not a valid html as pointed. About your question, the easiest and cleanner way, is to add a custom attribute on each <li> for example data-parent-element="category 1" and access that.

Comment: It is still not a valid syntax. An `ul` is not a valid child of `ul`, only `li` elements are valid child of an `ul`.

Comment: Ok.. if I'll change the 'categories' & 'category' to a div how I'll solve it?

Comment: Put the inner ul tags inside the li

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.subcategory', function(e){
 e.preventDefault;
  var text = $(this).parents('ul').first().prev().find('a').html();
  alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="categories">
  <li class="category">
    <a>category 1</a>
  </li>
  <ul class="subcategories">
    <li class="subcategory">
      <a>subcategory 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="subcategory">
      <a>subcategory 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul> <!-- tag should be closed here -->
  <li class="category">
    <a>category 2</a>
  </li>
  <ul class="subcategories">
    <li class="subcategory">
      <a>subcategory 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="subcategory">
      <a>subcategory 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="subcategory">
      <a>subcategory 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that the markup is invalid.

Comment: You should not assume that this will work, because the resulting DOM for the given HTML code might be different. The browser might introduce `li` elements to fix the invalide syntax.

Comment: This shouldn't be accepted as an answer as the markup is still invalid and can produce different results to what is expected

Comment: A comment with a fiddle doesn't fix the answer which is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to change HTML as it follow and then use jquery code:

```
<ul>
   <li class="category"><a>category 1</a></li>
   <li class="subcat">
       <ul>
           <li class="subcategory"><a>subcategory 1</a></li>
           <li class="subcategory"><a>subcategory 2</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="category"><a>category 2</a></li>
   <li class="subcat">
     <ul>
        <li class="subcategory"><a>subcategory 3</a></li>
        <li class="subcategory"><a>subcategory 4</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Jquery code -

```
$("li.subcategory").click(function(){
   console.log($(this).parents('.subcat').prev().find('a').text());
});
```

jsfiddle -  https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/j80hxhuw/1/

Comment: I would use `.closest('.subcat')`  instead of `.parents('.subcat')`, because `parents` will search up to the document root, while `closest` will stop searching at the first matching element.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to fix the HTML markup first as it follow:

```
<ul>
   <li class="category"><a>CATEGORY A</a>
       <ul>
           <li class="subcategory">SUBCATEGORY A1</li>
           <li class="subcategory">SUBCATEGORY A2</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="category"><a>CATEGORY B</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="subcategory">SUBCATEGORY B1</li>
        <li class="subcategory">SUBCATEGORY B2</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then use the following snippet of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.subcategory").click(function(){
        alert($(this).parent().prev().text());
    });
});
```

The alert function is just for display the right result, change with your needs.
Also here is a link to jsfiddle for a demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/y34adrhb/

Answer (score -1):

```
enter code here $("li").on("click",function(){
                    $(this).parent("ul").parent("ul").find("li").html();
                });
enter code here <ul>
                   <li></li>
                   <ul>
                      <li></li>
                      <li></li>
                   </ul>
                 </ul>
                <ul>
                   <li></li>
                   <ul>
                      <li></li>
                      <li></li>
                      <li></li>
                   </ul>
                 </ul>
```

You have to change your mark-up in this approach.